# Why is the UNICODE macro defined in my program

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I set character set to not set, and yet the UNICODE macro is defined. Test to satisfy the algorithm

Comment: C++ does not define this macro. Please be more specific.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you set it in Visual Studio, in project's properties.

This should work. Verify with gray color of `int i;`:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
int i;
#endif
```

Please show your test. Also, double-check if you set it for the current configuration and platform.